# SSL Handshake Optimisation

Tags: apache-2.2, ssl

My server seems to take a very long time (half the time of page load) to go through the initial ssl handshake process. I've tested the SSL load times using https://www.wormly.com/test_ssl it's telling me that I need to optimise my SSL Handshake Size.

Does anyone know how to do this/can point me in the direction of how to lean how to do this for a linux/Apache server, hopefully using WHM/Cpanel?

Thanks,

Matt

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Off the top of my head:

- Optimise the list of encryption ciphers offered as some are quicker than others
- Ensure you're sending any intermediate certificates to the client so it doesn't have to find them by other means
- Make sure you have keepalives enabled to minimise the number of connections for a given client and therefore the amount of times the handshake is performed
- What size key do you have? 2048-bit is probably the sweet spot between size, performance and security

Comment: 2048 bit so all good there. Just optimised the encryption cypher list and that speeded up things straight off the bat! Cheers!